# What is difference between Dynamic allocation and Static Allocation

Tags: dynamic, alloc

What is difference between Dynamic memory allocation and Static memory Allocation?

I don't understand this code:

```
int arrA[20];
int* arrB = new int [20];
```

What is the difference between those two lines?
Why does Dynamic allocation have array size?

Answer (score 0):

In static memory allocation, memory is allocated during compile-time.

Whereas in dynamic memory allocation, memory is allocated during run-time.

The `new` keyword is used for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Execuse me I have more question for you
Why Dynamic allocation defination array size?
 For example int* arrB = new int [20];

Comment: Yes, you may ask.

Comment: Size has to defined, whether static or dynamic allocation. Size tells how much memory your program needs.

Comment: I under stand very well~~~ Thank you^^

Comment: I could have upvoted your question, but sorry because I don't have enough reputation. +1 from my side.